# mongodb lookup aggregation query insert only one field

Tags: mongodb, lookup

I am quite new to mongodb and I understand the lookup function to create a join. My question is, instead of inserting the entire array or the right table, how can I only insert a specific field of the array?

Comment: explain with example

Comment: The entire premise of NoSQL datastores is to not have joins.

In NoSQL datastores you join on **write**, not on read.